# Switching between multiple full screen windows of a the same app across multiple displays

Tags: keyboard, display, windows, shortcut, fullscreen

I have two full screen windows of VSCode open, with ⌘+Tab I can switch between apps but not multiple windows of the same app.

With Ctrl+Arrow Keys I can navigate between windows inside a single screen but am not able to jump to another screen.

With Ctrl+(1-9) I can jump between desktops but still, I cannot navigate to another window if the same app.

Comment: To do this you need to give up fullscreen & use maximised instead, unless there's a 3rd party app to do it. Each fullscreen app is it's own Space. If you have 'displays have separate Spaces' *on*, then you would have to change each display separately. If it's *off* then one display will be blank.